# How do we find all possible values of r

Tags: calculus, education

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qERGB.jpg)

I need help with this question

Comment: Plz i made a mistake it should be f’(0) exist , so the derivative at 0 exist not f(0) ..

Comment: Please add your try

Comment: @Brien Navarro , i am new on the website, so i can describe what i do , i take the derivative of f at 0, then i got stuck coz i found f’(0)=-1 i dont get the question clear actually

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=2rx^{2r-1}arctan(\frac{1}{x})-\frac{x^{2r}}{1+x^2}$  Since $arctan(\frac{1}{x})$ is finite, $f'(0)=0$ for all $r\gt \frac{1}{2}$.  I don't see the restriction to $Q^+$.

Comment: How do you know that it is for r>(1/2) , coz this is what I expected also, but I don’t know the mathematical reason^^.

Comment: $arctan(\frac{1}{x})$ can be $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x=0$.  However $x^{2r-1}=0$ for $r\gt \frac{1}{2}$, so the product $=0$.  The other term is not a problem.